# invalid element type error with imported react component

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm using an imported component from an npm package, in two different apps.

In one app, it works perfectly, in the other one, it raises this error : `

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

How comes it only raises it in one app, since the package version and the import method are the same ?

The imported elemen is a React Component, bundled in commonJS, and it is the only exported element, therefore I'm importing it using

```
import ProductImage from '@balibart/product-image'
```

In both case, I'm passing it the same props. The component is supposed to render an SVG, and is exported using

```
module.exports = [a function]
```

I know that the component works just fine, because if I copy/paste its content in a separate file an import it using its path, it gets rendered just fine. The only option I see is in the way create-react-app imports it, but I'm pretty sure I used the same CRA version for both my apps...

Comment: Could you provide us more informations ? Especially code would be usefull.

Comment: @Tmba I added the import and export methods, and made sure the component is imported in the same way in both apps

Comment: What does the `package.json` dependency version look like for both apps? With semver, you might actually be using different versions of the package.

Comment: `module.exports` and `import` don't work that well together, some building systems have trouble with them (they wrap the default function into an object): That could be the problem. Are you using two different build versions?

Comment: @JonasWilms I don't think so, apps are pretty similar, bith using `create-react-app` as a boilerplate. And yes, I made sure I was using the same package version in both apps

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/706 ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone ever stumbles in this issue, make sure that your `webpack` versions are the same on both your applications. Mine was 3.5.1 on one app and 3.8.1 on the other, and that is what messed up my imports.